# Cakephp read() on a non-object in session when I call another Controller

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm working with Cakephp and I get a error with sessions when I call a method from another Controller.

**Error**
`Error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object`

**Controller Hotels**

```
App::import('Controller', 'Reports');
$Report = new ReportsController;
$Report->hotelsActivity($cabecera, $data, "Actividad Hotels Report");
```

**Method of Controller Reports**

```
function hotelsActivity($cabecera, $data, $nombre){
  $this->layout = false;
  $this->autoRender = false;
  $size = parent::excel($cabecera, $data, $nombre);

  $this->set('filesize',CakeNumber::toReadableSize($size));
  $this->set('counter',count($data));

  $this->render('new_reports');
}
```

**Header appController**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
      'Session'
    );

    public $helpers = array(
        'Session'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        //$this->Auth->allow();
        //$this->Auth->allow("*");
    }

    public function breadcump(){

        $model = $this->name;

        $breadcump = Array();
        foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
            switch($key){
              case "hotels_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Hotel";
                $breadcump_name = "Hotel";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "medics_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Medic";
                $breadcump_name = "Médico";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "users_id":
                $breadcump_model = "User";
                $breadcump_name = "Usuario";
                $breadcump_field = "user_name";
              break;
              case "manager_id":
                $breadcump_model = "User";
                $breadcump_name = "Manager";
                $breadcump_field = "user_name";
              break;
              case "group_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Group";
                $breadcump_name = "Grupo";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "nightusers_id":
                $breadcump_model = "User";
                $breadcump_name = "Responsable de noche";
                $breadcump_field = "user_name";
              break;
              case "hotelstypes_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Hotelstype";
                $breadcump_name = "Tipo";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "hotelsgroups_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Hotelsgroup";
                $breadcump_name = "Cadena";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "regions_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Region";
                $breadcump_name = "Region";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "zones_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Zone";
                $breadcump_name = "Zona";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "subzones_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Subzone";
                $breadcump_name = "Subzona";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "centres_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Centre";
                $breadcump_name = "Centro";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "ttoos_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Ttoo";
                $breadcump_name = "Tour Operador";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "incidencestypes_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Incidencestype";
                $breadcump_name = "Tipo";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "origins_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Origin";
                $breadcump_name = "Origen";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "ttoogroups_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Ttoogroup";
                $breadcump_name = "Grupo";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              case "ttoonationalities_id":
                $breadcump_model = "Ttoonationality";
                $breadcump_name = "Nacionalidad";
                $breadcump_field = "name";
              break;
              default:
                $breadcump_model = null;
            }

            // Condición para las búsquedas belongsto
            if($breadcump_model){
              if($value != ""){
                $breadcump[$key] = $value;
                $this->loadModel($breadcump_model);
                $conditions = array('conditions' => array($breadcump_model.'.id =' => $value), 'fields' => array($breadcump_model.'.'.$breadcump_field));
                $hotel = $this->$breadcump_model->find('all', $conditions);
                if($breadcump_name == "Responsable de noche"){
                  $breadcump[$breadcump_model."2"]['data_name'] = $breadcump_name;
                  $breadcump[$breadcump_model."2"]['data'] = $hotel[0][$breadcump_model][$breadcump_field];
                  $breadcump[$breadcump_model."2"]['id'] = $value;
                }
                else{
                  $breadcump[$breadcump_model]['data_name'] = $breadcump_name;
                  $breadcump[$breadcump_model]['data'] = $hotel[0][$breadcump_model][$breadcump_field];
                  $breadcump[$breadcump_model]['id'] = $value;
                }
              }
            }
            // Condición para las búsquedas fijas tipo fecha inicio, fecha fin, status..
            else{
              if($value != ""){
                if($key == "status"){
                    if ($model=="Incidences") {
                        $key = "Estado";
                        switch($value){
                          case 1: $value = "Activa"; break;
                          case 2: $value = "Finalizada"; break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $key = "Estado";
                        switch($value){
                          case 1: $value = "Aceptada"; break;
                          case 2: $value = "Asignada"; break;
                          case 3: $value = "Registrada"; break;
                          case 4: $value = "Anulada"; break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($key == "colaborator"){
                  switch($value){
                    case 'y': $value = "Sí"; break;
                    case 'n': $value = "No"; break;
                  }
                }
                if($key == "priority"){
                  $key = "Prioridad médico";
                }
                if($key =="dpd1"){
                    $key = "Fecha Inicio";
                }
                if($key =="dpd2"){
                    $key = "Fecha Fin";
                }

                $breadcump[$key] = $value;
                $breadcump[$key] = array('data_name' => $key, 'data' => $value);
              }
            }
        }

        return $breadcump;
    }

    public function excel($cabecera, $data, $report_type){

      $counter = count($data);
      $celdas = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z', 'AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG','AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AV','AW','AX','AY','AZ');

      // Importamos la clase PHPExcel
      App::import('Vendor', 'Classes/PHPExcel');
      App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
      App::uses('CakeNumber', 'Utility');

      $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

      $session = $this->request->session();
      $session->read('auth_user.User.user_name');

      // Set properties
      $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator($session->read('auth_user.User.user_name'));
      $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy($this->Session->read('auth_user.User.user_name'));
      $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("FreepApp ".$report_type);
      $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Autogenerated Excel File");
      $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("This is an automated excel file generated by IMS FreepApp Application");

      $filename = WWW_ROOT.'/files/tmp_report_'.$this->Session->read('auth_user.User.id').'.xlsx';

      $this->set('filename','tmp_report_'.$this->Session->read('auth_user.User.id').'.xlsx');

      //Sheet rename
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($report_type);

      //Creating Header
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', Configure::read('title') . ' ' . Configure::read('Ver') . ' Report System');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A2', 'Type');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', $report_type);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A3', 'Records');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B3', $counter);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A4', 'Date');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B4', date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time()));
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A5', 'User');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B5', $this->Session->read('auth_user.User.user_name'));
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:X1');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:X2');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B3:X3');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B4:X4');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B5:X5');

      //Header styles
      $style1 = array(
          'font' => array(
              'bold' => true,
              'size' => '18',
              'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffffff')

          ),
          'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,),
          'fill' => array(
              'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
              'color' => array('rgb' => '428bca')
          )
      );
      $style2 = array(
          'font' => array(
              'bold' => true,
              'size' => '14',
              'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffffff')
          ),
          'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,),
          'fill' => array(
              'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
              'color' => array('rgb' => '428bca')
          )
      );
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:X1')->applyFromArray($style1);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:B5')->applyFromArray($style2);

      //Title Bars
      for ($i=0; $i < count($cabecera); $i++) {
        if($i == 0){ $primeraCelda = "$celdas[$i]7"; }
        elseif( $i == (count($cabecera)-1) ){ $ultimaCelda = "$celdas[$i]7"; }
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("$celdas[$i]7", "$cabecera[$i]");
      }

      $header = "$primeraCelda:$ultimaCelda";
      $style = array(
          'font' => array('bold' => true,),
          'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,),
          'fill' => array(
              'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
              'color' => array('rgb' => 'E0E0E0')
          )
      );
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($header)->applyFromArray($style);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter("$primeraCelda:$ultimaCelda");

      $rowCount = 8;
      for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $contadorCeldas = 0;
        foreach ($data[$i] as $key => $arrayFinal) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("$celdas[$contadorCeldas]$rowCount", $data[$i][$key]);
              $contadorCeldas++;
        }
        $rowCount++;
      }

      //Set column autosize
      for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'AA'; $col++) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
              ->getColumnDimension($col)
              ->setAutoSize(true);
      }
      $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
      $objWriter->save($filename);

      $f = fopen($filename, 'r+');
      $stat = fstat($f);
      return $size = $stat['size'];

    }

}
```

**Line on get the error in parent Controller**

```
$this->Session->read('auth_user.User.user_name')
```

Comment: Why have you got the line `$Report = new ReportsController;` in your `HotelsController`? You should *never* be doing this! If you need to share functionality between controllers use a [Component](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html), put the shared functionality in `AppController` or use a [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

Add the component  into your controller

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

And inside your action:

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->read('auth_user.User.user_name');
```

Comment: I get error in "$session = $this->request->session();"

Comment: Error: Call to a member function session() on a non-object

Comment: Add the component to the controller please public $components = array(
    'Session'
);

Comment: App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
      'Session'
    );

    public $helpers = array(
        'Session'
    );

Comment: can you post your parent controller?

Comment: Yes! You can see appController

Comment: Try to put $session = $this->request->session(); inside the function beforeFilter and after call the var session

Comment: Method session does not exist

Comment: inside beforeFilter, lines 54 in $session = $this->request->session();

Comment: This need to works, there are a different problem inside your controller I think

Comment: Ok, I'll following searching the problem. Thanks you for your time!

Comment: If you will find The problem please let me know what was because i'm really curiuos about it

Answer (score -1):

Define sessionhelper in app controller :

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session'
);

public $helpers = array(
    'Session'
);
}
```

Then try it:

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->read('auth_user.User.user_name');
```

Comment: The same error: Call to a member function session() on a non-object

Comment: can you show me Controller Hotels full page and app controler